How can I check Google Gemini API key is valid or not
I want to make a image recognition system that uses Google Gemini.
The system recognize an image by using 2 methods, that are rule based logic and logic with Gemini.
Therefore I'd check if Gemini API key is correct and if that is incorrect then use only rule based logic.
I'm searching for the way of validate Gemini API key, one simple way is just send request with given API key.
But this way takes so much time. And even though API failed, it is difficult to distinguish the error is caused by incorrect API key or not.
So are there any good way to check Gemini API key?
Environment:
OS:Ubuntu
language: Python3.11

The best way to check if it works is to use it.  If it doesn't work it will fail just catch the exception.
So make your call and if it fails you know you cant use it.

question acknowledges that this is an option but doesn't want to do it. For whatever reason.

certainly. When a key is provided by user and that is incorrect, the system should be killed.

@k_ug the thing is this is a key generated by google there is no validation method that can be preformed locally.  Its not a JWT or anything like that that you could validate.   The only way to validate keys is to use them and wait for them to fail.   Its also important not to run a dummy test users will be charged every time you use their key.

@julaine I understand that but that doesn't make the answer wrong :)

This answer is correct. Google API Keys are opaque objects. AFAIK there is no public endpoint you can call to verify an API Key. My suggestion is to use the list models REST endpoint https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1/models or https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models to verify that the key works and that you have access to the Gemini model your code is using. The endpoint should respond fast enough for your needs but verify yourself. Many changes are occurring with Gemini, so verifying available models in your code is a recommended feature to implement.

thank you all. I am going to delete check function and leave it to user
